# Publishing an interview/conversations in a book without explicit consent

Tags: copyright, publishing, right-of-publicity

Let's say I've conducted an interview/conversation as the interviewer with someone. I didn't tell him I may publish that interview (in a book or elsewhere) as I wasn't thinking of publishing it at the time of the interview.

Do I need to seek further consent before publishing the interview or parts of it for commercial or not commercial ends? What if the interviewed person died and couldn't be reached before?

Comment: Sorry your grammar is confusing - I can't tell if either you or the interviewer did nor did not give permission to publish

Comment: @mmmmmm I've edited. hope it is clearer now. I was the interviewer, and didn't ask for any permission to publish.

Comment: I hope I met the target in the cleanup.

Comment: In what country did this happen? laws on this may differ.

Comment: @DavidSiegel, Let's say I want to publish online and/or the US. The interviews were conducted online. someone from Europe (Sweden) and US.

Comment: See https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/72792/publishing-non-commercially-a-video-interview-with-a-celebrity-online-without